# Multiple flume agent on same machine

Tags: hadoop, hbase, flume

I have a problem statement where i need to collect data from multiple machines(each machine forwarding data for different format) to centralized storage(Hbase).

I need to make a different table for each type of log collected.

How can i do it using flume? 
Is it possible to run multiple flume agent on same machine ? 
I can assign each type to one agent which will write to hbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just configure them all up in the same flume.conf and restart your agent.

You'll need a different source, channel and sink for each different stream of data. You can plumb them any way you wish.